# Visitors List Per Day on Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to have a script that would allow me to track the visitors (by gmail username or associated RL name) to certain Google Docs and email me a list daily. I am the owner of the docs in question and I have shared these docs only with certain users, but for some reason anonymous users keep showing up. I want to be able to track the problem (I can't be staring at the open doc all day to see who visits) so I can show it's an ongoing issue to Google if it continues. Would anyone here be able to help me with this? I'd really appreciate it. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: If you have more than one Google account, use the Google account that doesn't have permission, and see if you can open the doc.  How do you know that an anonymous user is loading your Doc?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in with a Google account, this code, put into an attached script might work:

```
/**
 * The onOpen function runs automatically when the Google Docs document is
 * opened. Use it to add custom menus to Google Docs that allow the user to run
 * custom scripts. For more information, please consult the following two
 * resources.
 *
 * Extending Google Docs developer guide:
 *     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs
 *
 * Document service reference documentation:
 *     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/
 */
function onOpen() {
  // Log the email address of the person running the script.
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);
  // The code below creates a new spreadsheet "People" and logs the URL for it
  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("People");
  // The code below opens a spreadsheet using its ID and logs the name for it.
  // Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
  // It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");
  Logger.log(ss.getName());
  // Appends a new row with 1 column to the bottom of the
  // spreadsheet containing the values in the array
  ss.appendRow([email]);
}
```

Comment: OnOpen will not execute anything that requires authorization because it runs silently without user consent and. Have you tried the above code?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  No, I didn't try the above code.  My sincere apologies.  I take full responsibility for my actions.